# white mail if no attachment

Tags: php, email

I have a partially working email code (don't come with the phpmailer stuff), it is sending emails WITH attachments, but once I send a file without an attachment it does send but with a WHITE, no text.

Why is it sending a white email if I only send text:

This is the form all within a query:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    // output data of each row
        echo "
        <form method='post' name='contact_form'
    action='/bedankt-verzenden?id=". $id ."' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Naar wie verzend u het voorstel:<br />
        <input style='width: 100%;' type='text' name='name' value='" . $row["firstname"] . "'><br/><br />
        Email:<br />
        <input style='width: 100%;' type='text' name='email' value='Jouw email'><br /><br />
        Onderwerp van het bericht:<br />
        <input style='width: 100%;' type='text' name='title' value='Offerte voor uw ". $row["stijlkeuken"] ." keuken'><br /><br />
        Bericht:<br />
        <textarea style='width: 100%; height: 200px;' name='message'></textarea><br /><br /><br />
        Bestand uploaden:<br />
        <input type='file' name='File_upload[]' size='40' multiple='multiple' ><br /><br />
        <input style='width: 100%; display: none;' type='text' name='email2' value='". $row["email"] ."'>
        <input type='submit' value='Verzenden' class='clicky-submitty' id='clicky-submitty2'>
        </form>";

}
```

Then this is the handler (edited), also within a query:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $recipient_email    = $_POST['email2']; //recepient
    $from_email         = $_POST['email']; //from email using site domain.
    $subject            = $_POST['title']; //email subject line

    $sender_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender email
    $sender_message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message
    $attachments = $_FILES['File_upload'];

    $file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
    $boundary = md5(time());
    $eol = "\r\n";

if(empty($_FILES['File_upload']))
{

    //header
        $headers = 'From: info@keukenaanbod.nl' . $eol; 
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $sender_email . $eol;
        $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $sender_email . $eol;
        $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . time() . " TheSystem@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">" . $eol; 
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v" . phpversion() . $eol;
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $eol;
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8 boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\"";


                $body = "--". $boundary . $eol;
                $body .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" . $eol;
                $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol . $eol;
                $body .= "Er is gereageerd op jouw keuken aanvraag, reageer op deze mail om in contact te komen:". $eol . $sender_message . $eol . $eol;

    }else{  

        //header
        $headers = 'From: info@keukenaanbod.nl' . $eol; 
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $sender_email . $eol;
        $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $sender_email . $eol;
        $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . time() . " TheSystem@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">" . $eol; 
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v" . phpversion() . $eol;
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\""; 

        //attachments
        for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++){      
            if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])){

                //get file info
                $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
                $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
                $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];

                //read file
                $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$x], "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)

                $body = "--". $boundary . $eol;
                $body .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" . $eol;
                $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol . $eol;
                $body .= "Er is gereageerd op jouw keuken aanvraag, reageer op deze mail om in contact te komen:". $eol . $sender_message . $eol . $eol;
                $body .= "--" . $boundary . $eol;
                $body .= "Content-Type: " . $file_type. "; name=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $eol;
                $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol; 
                $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $eol . $eol;
                $body .= $encoded_content . $eol . $eol;
            }
        }
    }


     $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {      
        header('Location: /verzenden-gelukt?id='. $id .'');
    }else{
        die('Email kon helaas niet verzonden worden, u dient direct uit te zoeken wat er gaande is!');  
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are no attachments, what is it supposed to send as the text?

Comment: I don't understand why you have a `for` loop in the `if` block. If `$_FILES['File_upload']` is empty, then what are you looping over?

Comment: There is a form in earlier stage, the form should send the text Er is gereageerd op jouw keuken aanvraag, reageer op deze mail om in contact te komen:". $eol . $sender_message . $eol . $eol;

Of wich $sender_message is the message send from the form.
This si working perfectly, only when there are no attachments it is not sending a body... only the headers

Comment: Show that part of the script. It's impossible to answer if you don't show how you're doing it.

Comment: You're probably getting an error. If there are no attachments, then `$attachments` is empty and `$attachments['name']` is `NULL`, so `count($attachments['name'])` will get an error.

Comment: Well at first I had if ($file_count > 0){}
This is giving me excactly the same problem. If i changed the if ($file_count < 10){} then it started working.

But of course the attachments then didn't work.. But the text in plain emails were suddenly showing..
I edited my question (changed code) and added the form!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there was a pretty straight forward refactor that you could do to make your code a bit more dry. If you notice in my answer I move all the header and body stuff out of the if and else. This allows you to remove the else all together.

Rather than checking for names not being empty you should go for the built in errors PHP will throw.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $recipient_email    = $_POST['email2']; //recepient
    $from_email         = $_POST['email']; //from email using site domain.
    $subject            = $_POST['title']; //email subject line

    $sender_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);         //capture sender email
    $sender_message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message

    $boundary = md5(time());
    $eol = "\r\n";

    //header
    $headers = 'From: info@keukenaanbod.nl' . $eol; 
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $sender_email . $eol;
    $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $sender_email . $eol;
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . time() . " TheSystem@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">" . $eol; 
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v" . phpversion() . $eol;
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\""; 

    $body = "--". $boundary . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol . $eol;
    $body .= "Er is gereageerd op jouw keuken aanvraag, reageer op deze mail om in contact te komen:". $eol . $sender_message . $eol . $eol;

    if (isset($_FILES['File_upload'])){//Use isset on the file to verify it was uploaded
        //Check each files error
        foreach ($_FILES["File_upload"]["error"] as $key => $error){
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){//If the error was ok then do your thang
                //Use the $key get file info
                $file_name = $_FILES["File_upload"]['name'][$key];
                $file_size = $_FILES["File_upload"]['size'][$key];
                $file_type = $_FILES["File_upload"]['type'][$key];

                $handle = fopen($_FILES["File_upload"]['tmp_name'][$key], "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)
                $body .= "--" . $boundary . $eol;
                $body .= "Content-Type: " . $file_type. "; name=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $eol;
                $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol; 
                $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $eol . $eol;
                $body .= $encoded_content . $eol . $eol;
            }
        }    
    }


    $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail){//output success or failure messages
        header('Location: /verzenden-gelukt?id='. $id .'');
    } else {
        die('Email kon helaas niet verzonden worden, u dient direct uit te zoeken wat er gaande is!');  
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I used your code as is, but the attachments are now shown as algebra. No document in the attachments nor images are shown!

Though, the normal text is showing right now. So still not working.

Comment: @HenkRensenbrink Sorry about that I do not have anything to test on right now. Please try the update I did not have the body correctly placed for some of the file logic.

Comment: well don't worry your code did gave me the solution. I will update my answer and give you the points. Thanks for the great option :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that solved my issue, I can now send emails in php() with and without attachment and gives my email an body!

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $recipient_email    = $_POST['email2']; //recepient
    $from_email         = $_POST['email']; //from email using site domain.
    $subject            = $_POST['title']; //email subject line

    $sender_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender email
    $sender_message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message
    $attachments = $_FILES['File_upload'];

    $file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
    $boundary = md5(time());
    $eol = "\r\n";

    if (isset($_FILES['File_upload'])){

        //attachments
        for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++){      
            if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])){

                //get file info
                $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
                $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
                $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];

                //read file
                $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$x], "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)
            }
        }
    }

    //header
        $headers = 'From: info@keukenaanbod.nl' . $eol; 
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $sender_email . $eol;
        $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $sender_email . $eol;
        $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . time() . " TheSystem@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">" . $eol; 
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v" . phpversion() . $eol;
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\""; 

        $body = "--". $boundary . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol . $eol;
        $body .= "Er is gereageerd op jouw keuken aanvraag, reageer op deze mail om in contact te komen:". $eol . $sender_message . $eol . $eol;
            if (isset($_FILES['File_upload'])){
        $body .= "--" . $boundary . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: " . $file_type. "; name=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol; 
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $eol . $eol;
        $body .= $encoded_content . $eol . $eol;
            }


     $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {      
        header('Location: /verzenden-gelukt?id='. $id .'');
    }else{
        die('Email kon helaas niet verzonden worden, u dient direct uit te zoeken wat er gaande is!');  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you assign `$attachments = $_FILES['File_upload'];` *before* you test `if (isset($_FILES['File_upload']))`. If it's not set, the assignment will complain about an undefined index.